# Did the rules for filing a 1099-MISC change this year?

Tags: united-states, taxes, rental-property

My property manager just sent me a W-9 (request for taxpayer ID) and asked me to send it back to her.  When I asked her about this last year for my 2010 taxes, she said it wasn't necessary, even though I was paid more than $600 by her that year as well.

Are there more situations this year for filing (and receiving) a 1099-MISC?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There was a [substantial change in 1099 reporting](http://www.greenleafaccounting.com/change-in-1099-reporting), included in the Health Care act commonly known as "ObamaCare". Basically, it is much more required to fill out a 1099, with the idea that increased revenues produced by such will help pay for Health Care. This [requirement was later repealed](http://www.greenleafaccounting.com/new-1099-requirements-repealed), as it was very unpopular. Still, there has been increased awareness of 1099 forms as a result. It has been the case that for services provided, a 1099 form should be filled out, if the services exceed $600. The official IRS instructions can be found [here](http://www.irs.gov/instructions/i1099msc/ar02.html).

Comment: Bottom line is that there's no difference in requirements between 2010 and 2011.